# Does Tortoise SVN throttle downloads?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, bandwidth-throttling

I am pulling a massive repository from CloudForge using Tortoise SVN.  My download speeds always seem to cap out at 1,500 kBytes/sec.

[image]

I get this speed on my internet at work, as expected.  But with my 150/150 mbps internet at home, I get the same speed.

Is this speed being throttled, or is there something else going on here?  If it is being throttled, is this happening on the client-side (Tortoise SVN) or the server-side (CloudForge)?  Why?

Comment: Ask CloudForge. TortoiseSVN and SVN itself do not limit the transfer rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tortoise SVN does not throttle download speeds (Thanks @bahrep).

I downloaded the same repository from Assembla, and I can confirm that CloudForge does throttle download speeds.